# Proxy and Concrete Class in Java

Tags: java, spring, proxy

Consider this junit code

```
XXXimpl xxxImpl=(XXXImpl) new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(context).getBean("xxxx");
```

It throws exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy42 incompatible with com.zzz.yyy.xxxImpl

When I do ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(context)getBean("xxx").getClass() it gives $Proxy 42.

I have a similar setup in another application but getClass returns the concrete class "XXX" instead of $Proxy 42.

When I searched for this error, it mentioned classloaders. So I looked at the class path but could not find the issue.

Can someone guide as to why two applications with similar setup  - one returns proxy and the other returns concrete class.

Comment: Your configuration, for whatever reason, is set up to proxy your `xxxx` bean. It used JDK proxies to do this.

Comment: Can you post your spring config

Comment: What is your complete technology stack?

Comment: Probably your bean uses `@Transactional` which causes Spring using a proxy for your class, or maybe another configuration. We cannot know this unless we see your bean definition via annotations or XML, tho.

Comment: Also, you should not try to attempt to work with the implementation class directly. If you're writing real unit tests, initialize the class by using `new`. If you're going to retrieve the *class* via Spring, then you're writing integration tests and you should use interfaces only.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza One of the method has Transactional in the XXXImpl. I believe as per your earlier comment "causes Spring using a proxy for your class" therefore it is returning proxy. I am just learning Junit..I have to test one of the methods in that class but that method does not use Transactional. So can you please how I can test the method. Thank you.